# API not returning latest data in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, api, caching, laravel-8

I am using laravel 8 for my flutter app. In this, Api's are not returning latest data after edit/update. Even on another api of getting that data.

To add data I am following code:

```
$input = $request->all();
            $validation = Validator::make($input, [
                // 'image' => 'required|image|max:2048',
                'user_id' => 'required',
                'team_name' => 'required',
                'description' => 'required',
                'status' => 'required',
                'members' => 'required'
            ]);

            if ($validation->fails()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'data' => '',
                    'message' => implode(',\n', $validation->errors()->all()),
                ]);
                exit();
            }

            if (isset($request['team_name']) && !empty($request['members']) && !empty($request['description']) && !empty($request['status'])) {
                $team_url = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $request['team_name']));
                $check_record = TeamModel::where('team_name', $request['team_name'])->count();
                if ($check_record > 0) {
                    /* means already exists */
                    return response()->json([
                        'success' => false,
                        'message' => 'Team name already exists',
                        'data' => []
                    ], 200);
                    die();
                }
            }

            // $name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $teamModel = new TeamModel();

            // uploading image starts
            if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

                $fileName = 'teams-' . time() . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = $request->file('image')->move('images', $fileName);
                $teamModel->image = 'images/' . $fileName;
            }

            // uploading image ends

            // $teamModel->image = 'images/';

            $teamModel->team_name = $input['team_name'];
            $teamModel->team_url = Str::slug($request['team_name'], '_');
            $teamModel->description = $input['description'];
            $teamModel->created_by = $input['user_id'];
            $teamModel->status = $input['status'];

            if ($teamModel->save()) {

                $members  = array($input['user_id']);
                // $request['members']['owner'] = 1;
                if (!empty($request['members'])) {
                    $members = array_merge($members, $input['members']);
                }
                //Add Member
                if (!empty($members)) {
                    foreach ($members as $mem) {
                        $isSelf = $input['user_id'] == $mem ? 1 : 0;
                        // $owner = auth()->user()->id == $mem ? 1 : 0;
                        $arrData = [
                            'team_id' => $teamModel->id,
                            'user_id' => $mem,
                            'request_by' => $input['user_id'],
                            'is_accepted' => $isSelf,
                            'seen_status' => $isSelf,
                            'owner' => $isSelf
                        ];
                        DB::table('team_members')->insert($arrData);
                    }
                }

                // $teamModel->image = $base_url . $teamModel->image;
                if ($teamModel->image != null || !empty($teamModel->image))
                    $teamModel->image = $base_url . $teamModel->image;
                else
                    $teamModel->image = '';

                return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'message' => 'Team created successfully',
                    'data' => $teamModel
                ], 200);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'message' => 'Unable to create team! Please try again.',
                    'data' => $teamModel
                ], 200);
            }
```

To update code:

```
 $id = $input['id'];

            if (!isset($input['members'])) {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Please select team members first!',
                    'data' => []
                ], 200);
            }



            $input = $request->all();


            $validation = Validator::make($input, [
                // 'image' => 'required|image|max:2048',
                'id' => 'required',
                'user_id' => 'required',
                'team_name' => 'required',
                'description' => 'required',
                'status' => 'required',
                'members' => 'required'
            ]);

            if ($validation->fails()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'data' => '',
                    'message' => implode(',\n', $validation->errors()->all()),
                ]);
                exit();
            }

            if (isset($request['team_name']) && !empty($request['members']) && !empty($request['description']) && !empty($request['status'])) {
                $team_url = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $request['team_name']));
                $check_record = TeamModel::where('team_name', $request['team_name'])->count();
                if ($check_record > 1) {
                    /* means already exists */
                    return response()->json([
                        'success' => false,
                        'message' => 'Team name already exists',
                        'data' => []
                    ], 200);
                    die();
                }
            }


            $teamModel = TeamModel::find($id);

            $teamModel->team_name = $request['team_name'];

            $teamModel->description = $request['description'];
            $teamModel->team_url = Str::slug($request['team_name'], '_');

            // uploading image starts
            if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
                if (file_exists($teamModel->image)) {
                    unlink($teamModel->image);
                }

                $fileName = 'teams-' . time() . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $path = $request->file('image')->move('images', $fileName);
                $teamModel->image = 'images/' . $fileName;
            }

            // uploading image ends

            $teamModel->status = $request['status'];
            if ($teamModel->save()) {

                //Add Member
                $members = $input['members'];
                if (!empty($members)) {
                    foreach ($members as $mem) {
                        $isSelf = $input['user_id'] == $mem ? 1 : 0;
                        $arrData = [
                            'team_id' => $teamModel->id,
                            'user_id' => $mem,
                            'request_by' => $input['user_id'],
                            'is_accepted' => $isSelf,
                            'seen_status' => $isSelf
                        ];
                        if (!team_member($teamModel->id, $mem))
                            DB::table('team_members')->insert($arrData);
                    }
                }

                if ($teamModel->image != null || !empty($teamModel->image))
                    $teamModel->image = $base_url . $teamModel->image;
                else
                    $teamModel->image = '';

                return response()->json([
                    'success' => true,
                    'message' => 'Team updated successfully',
                    'data' => $teamModel
                ], 200);
            } else {

                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'Unable to update team! please try again.',
                    'data' => []
                ], 200);
            }
```

I am using following way to return response:

```
return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Success message',
            'data' => $data
        ], 200);
```

I have explored many articles and tried clearing cache by commands but none of them is worked. I am not able to understand why it's getting too much cache even on json.

Comment: please add more details in question. & add your sample code of edit update operation

Comment: I have added insertion and updated code

Comment: you are doing something wrong i believe:  -1-first you save a model to the db  -2-then you you modify the image value of the model without updating the database  -3-lastly you return the updated model to the user (but the db still has the old value of image in the db, you are basically returning a non- existent model). is that how it should work?

Comment: you made mistake. after TeamModel save you made some changes like `image path` but lastly you return the latest updated model without saving it into Database. so, before you return it as a response, you need to save that updated model data into db if you made some changes in model after last changes.

Comment: @MdFarzan your problem has solved? if yes than you can write self answer at below of this question so it helps to other people. If not solved than ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. It was the cache issue from the server. To figure out this issue, I tested my code on another server.